# How to conditionally apply CSS classes in Angular child component based on input value?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list component:

```
<section class="p-10 flex flex-col gap-10">
  <p class="text-xl font-black text-blue-700">Transfer history</p>
  <div class="flex flex-col gap-10">
    @for(item of history; track item.person){
    <app-history-item
      [person]="item.person"
      [date]="item.date"
      [amount]="item.amount"
      [type]="item.type"
    ></app-history-item>
    }
  </div>
</section>
```

and a child component:

```
<div
  class="flex items-center justify-center gap-10 px-10 py-2 rounded-2xl shadow-md w-fit"
>
  <p class="font-bold text-lg">{{ person }}</p>
  <p class="text-gray-700">{{ date }}</p>
  <p class="font-bold text-lg">{{ amount }} $</p>
  <div
    class="px-6 py-1 rounded-3xl font-bold text-md w-fit items-center flex justify-items-center"
  >
    {{ type }}
  </div>
</div>
```

how to add `bg-red-100 text-red-700`  to

```
  <div
        class="px-6 py-1 rounded-3xl font-bold text-md w-fit items-center flex justify-items-center"
      >
        {{ type }}
      </div>
```

if a type is expense? Or green if an income? Using tailwind css classes.

i tried:

```
 [class]="{
      'bg-green-100 text-green-700': type === 'income',
      'bg-red-100 text-red-700': type === 'expense'
    }"
```

or

```
 [ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-100 text-green-700': type === 'income', 'bg-red-100 text-red-700': type === 'expense' }"
```

but it didnt work.

EDIT:
the data i work with

```
 history: any[] = [
    {
      person: 'Max',
      date: '22 Jan 2022',
      amount: '200',
      type: 'Income',
    },
    {
      person: 'Kate',
      date: '24 Aug 2021',
      amount: '150',
      type: 'Expense',
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you are working with? expecially the type

Comment: thanks sir for help! i edited and provided the data!

Comment: Ok, so in the data you provided `Income` and `Expense` have a capital letter. Try to see if that fixes the `ngClass` snippet .

Answer (score 2):

As per the data you provided, the type variable can assume the exact values `Expense` and `Income` but in the example provided you are checking against `expense` and `income`.

Fixing the case in the same `ngClass` snippet you provided should fix the problem.

`[ngClass]="{ 'bg-green-100 text-green-700': type === 'Income', 'bg-red-100 text-red-700': type === 'Expense' }"`

To use the `ngClass` you also need to add an import of the `CommonModule`

Comment: and i have to import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; and put it in the imports! thanks!